# Можно ли такое реализовать в вордпресс?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

задача такая: скрыть из общей ленты записей некоторые записи фильтруя их по меткам, а не рубрикам (как это делают многие плагины).

или же как записи с метками автоматически добавлять в одноименные рубрики, чтобы использовать обычный плагин тогда по рубрикам.

Comment: Задача не ясна, куча лишней информации, нечитабельный текст. А в ВП не может быть записей вне рубрик.

Comment: А что вам мешает ложить все в 1 рубрику, но в сайдбаре вместо списка категорий выводить список тегов? Да, не особо логично, но это решает ваш вопрос. Просто метки оформите в виде списка категорий

Comment: @eugene_v  мне нужно отфильтровать и скрыть из общей ленты записей некоторые записи. но так как рубрика в блоге всего одна то плагины не подходят, потому что фильтруют и скрывают только по рубрикам.

Comment: @SeVlad я изменила вопрос. мне не надо выводить ни метки ни рубрики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день!
На англоязычном stack по Wordpress был задан подобный вопрос.
Ознакомьтесь пожалуйста.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154878/exclude-posts-from-homepage-having-a-specified-tag

Или вот ещё:

https://wpsites.net/web-design/3-ways-to-exclude-posts-with-specific-tag-i-ds-from-displaying-in-your-loop/

http://wp-snippets.com/exclude-posts-with-certain-tag-from-loop/

Comment: спасибо. мне понравился такой вариант. работает, кажется. https://wpsites.net/web-design/3-ways-to-exclude-posts-with-specific-tag-i-ds-from-displaying-in-your-loop/